# How to get both data results & counts from aggregate in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm stuck in an issue
I'm using aggregate in three collections. So, I want the result of aggregation + count of results in a single query, but since I am using a limit also in aggregate so I want the total count but not for limit only.
Here is my query

```
var partnerCollection = [
    { $lookup: {
      from: "courses",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "partnerId",
      as: "courses"
    } },
    {
        $project:
        {
            "_id":1,
            "partnerName":1,
            "phone":1,
            "email":1,
            "website":1,
            "address":1,
            "companyId":1,
            "courses.courseName": 1,
            "courses.courseType":1,
            "courses.totalCost":1,
            "courses.costPerWeek":1
        }
    },
    {
        $match: findUserDataCondition
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            [sortby] : sortType
        }
    },
    {
        $skip : start
    },
    {
        $limit : length
    } ];

partnerBusiness.aggregate(partnerCollection, (error, result) => {
});
```

I want to get result of above query (including $limit) + count (of all matching collections , for count I want to ignore $limit),
Please help me to figure this out.

I want my result be like

```
data: [{ _id: 5d02e292a9ce94663c6aafd6,
    partnerName: 'aaaa',
    email: 'aaaa@jcub.edu.au',
    phone: '1300935386',
    website: 'abc.com',
    companyId: 5ce3548c52e4920ae3f3f12f,
    courses: []
  }, { _id: 5d02e292a9ce94663c6aafd6,
    partnerName: 'bbb',
    email: 'bbb@jcub.edu.au',
    phone: '1300935386',
    website: 'abc.com',
    companyId: 5ce3548c52e4920ae3f3f12f,
    courses: []
  },
  { ........ },
],
count : 90
```

Comment: Can you post please sample data + expected result?

Comment: I have posted the sample answer

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60775167/11717458), can you check please?

Comment: SHIVAM did you check the answer I posted? If that doesn't help, can you add sample data to the question? You only added the expected result.

Comment: @SuleymanSah Thanks dear, it really worked.

Comment: I am happy that it worked, if you want you can delete this question.

Comment: Let it be.
It may be useful for someone else too.

Comment: Ok, then can I mark this as duplicate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211072/discussion-between-shivam-sharma-and-suleymansah).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get count of the Documents and filter them in efficient way? (mongoose)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60770129/how-can-i-get-count-of-the-documents-and-filter-them-in-efficient-way-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

Use toArray method on aggregate and then you can find its length